# code runs but instanceof failes when importing via tsconfig path

Tags: typescript, import, mocha.js, instanceof

Some odd behaviour here. I'm writing an unit test using Mocha which calls a static method of a Class that converts a LatLng to a leaflet L.LatLng object. At the end of the test I'm checking if the returned object is indeed an instance of L.LatLng. Surprisingly that test failed even though it really is an instance of L.LatLng. After poking around for a few hours I was able to narrow the problem down to the following.
If I import the Converter class via the tsconfig path parameter

```
import { LeafletConverter } from '@maps/leaflet/leaflet-converter';
```

Then the test fails. But if I import it via relative path:

```
import { LeafletConverter } from '../../../app/maps/leaflet/leaflet-converter';
```

Then the test passes with no error. Question is, what is going on here and is there a way I can keep the '@maps/...' import style?

**Versions:**

```
$ tsc --version
Version 3.6.3
```

VSCode 1.39.2

**Test file:**

```
    import { expect } from 'chai';
    import 'mocha';
    import L from "leaflet";
    import { LeafletConverter as DirectLeafletConverter } from '../../../app/maps/leaflet/leaflet-converter';
    import { LeafletConverter } from '@maps/leaflet/leaflet-converter';
    import { LatLng } from '@maps/lat-lng';


    describe.only('maps/leaflet/asdf', () => {


        it('tsconfig path import - this test fails', () => {
            const leafletll = LeafletConverter.toLeafletLatLng(new LatLng(1,2));
            const test = leafletll instanceof L.LatLng;
            expect(test).to.be.true;
        });

        it('direct import - this test passes', () => {
            const leafletll = DirectLeafletConverter.toLeafletLatLng(new LatLng(1,2));
            const test = leafletll instanceof L.LatLng;
            expect(test).to.be.true;
        });


    });
```

**LeafletConverter.ts**

```
    import { LatLng } from "@maps/lat-lng";
    import L from "leaflet";
    import { LatLngBounds } from "@maps/lat-lng-bounds";

    export abstract class LeafletConverter {
        private constructor(){}

...


        public static toLeafletLatLng(latLng: LatLng): L.LatLng  {
            let result: L.LatLng = null;

            if(LatLng.isValid(latLng)) {
                result = L.latLng(latLng.lat,latLng.lng);
            }

            return result;
        }

...

    }
```

**Test command & output:**

```
$ "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" --inspect-brk=22915 node_modules\\mocha\\bin\\_mocha -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register --timeout 30000 --colors C:\\Users\\Asdf\\tmp\\rm.js\\group
test/**/*.test.ts
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:22915/e1b8ec38-90ac-41dd-aded-c2c20e2ffa28
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.


  maps/leaflet/asdf
    1) tsconfig path import
    √ direct import        


  1 passing (14ms)
  1 failing

  1) maps/leaflet/asdf
       tsconfig path import:

      AssertionError: expected false to be true
      + expected - actual

      -false
      +true

      at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Asdf\tmp\rm.js\group-clusterer\src\test\maps\leaflet\asdf.test.ts:16:27)



Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "typescript-webpack-seed-project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register src/test/**/*.test.ts",
    "compile": "npx tsc",
    "cc": "npx tsc -w",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.3",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.38.0",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.5.5",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.7",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.5",
    "@types/q": "^1.5.2",
    "@types/rbush": "^2.0.3",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "jsdom": "15.2.1",
    "jsdom-global": "3.0.2",
    "leaflet": "^1.5.1",
    "mocha": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.4.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "tslint": "^5.20.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "rbush": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Root cause of the problem is the absolute path to the ts files in the mocha command line command.
When I modify this...

```
$ "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" --inspect-brk=22915 node_modules\\mocha\\bin\\_mocha -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register --timeout 30000 --colors C:\\Users\\Asdf\\tmp\\rm.js\\group-clusterer/src/test/**/*.test.ts
```

to this...

```
$ "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" --inspect-brk=22915 node_modules\\mocha\\bin\\_mocha -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register --timeout 30000 --colors src/test/**/*.test.ts
```

Then everything works fine. Why that is? I've no idea...